# How can I trigger an update to all the autolayout constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I modified programmatically one autolayout constraint. It takes effect on one certain view, but other views that are bound with other constraints to that view, do not change their positions. Is there an "**updateAllConstraints**" method?

Comment: Maybe you coud post a screen of your constraints: the only think I may suppose is that these other views are somehow bounded to other elements by non-stretchable constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that constrains were not set up properly, and in this case non of the setNeedsLayout or updateConstraintsIfNeeded can help.

Answer (score 39):

Call those two methods on the view you want to be updated:

```
-setNeedsLayout
-layoutIfNeeded
```

The first one says to the layout system that this view needs to be laid out, because it has some changes and, everything should be recalculated. The second force the layout system to be run now, layout system is triggered at specific times during runtime, with this method you are saying:"do it now".

Comment: Can i change constrains of an Imageview through UIButton click? If so, How please explain as i am new in this.

Comment: Totally agree with this answer!

Comment: @Sofeda sure you can. In your UIButton's action method you could remove the constraints of the UIImageView  with e.g. `view.removeConstraints(imageView)` and then set new constraints.

Comment: The code given in the answer will also recalculate the constraints even if the view is not attached to the hierarchy

Answer (score 4):

Yes There is a method on UIView called `- (void)updateConstraintsIfNeeded`

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraintsIfNeeded

However I don't think this is your problem

Answer (score -2):

Those of you that come across this topic, and are looking where to find this in the menus.

Best I have found is:

1. Select the items that you want to "pop" back to your constraints
2. Top menu: Editor/Update Frames (or/) shortcut: command + option + =

Hopefully this helps

Comment: The question was on how to do it programmatically. Your answer is correct, but unfortunately does not fit that question

Comment: Yes @Taier,  I have edited my post to reflect your comment, thank you.

Comment: almost 1 year :)