# Auto Layout constraints updated but not reflecting in view on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I recently started developing an iOS app. I set auto layout constraints for topAnchors of a number of views, but none of them are being updated on device rotation.

```
headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outlineView.topAnchor, constant: headerAnchor).isActive = true
// headerAnchor is a calculated value which changes with orientation change.
```

I even tried changing the constants with a function and calling it in viewWillTransition.

Upon checking the debug view hierarchy it says:
view.top = view.top + 110.4 @ 1100

^ that 110.4 is the value for portrait orientation. on rotation it changes to 48.6, but is not reflected on the view. Tried calling view.layoutIfNeeded, view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded in viewWillTransition.

Edit: function updating the value of constant

```
 var headerViewTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
.
.
.
 headerViewTopAnchor = headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outlineView.topAnchor, constant: headerAnchor) 
.
.
.
func updateConstraintConstants() {
headerViewTopAnchor?.constant = headerAnchor
}
```

Then i call this function in viewWillTransition. All of them contain the updated values.

Comment: refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20451936/1746086

Comment: Are you *updating* the constraint or *adding a new* constraint?

Comment: @shahnilay86 i called both of them in viewWillTransition on main view, still doesn't work? Should i be calling them somewhere else ?

Comment: @DonMag the constraint contains a variable which updates on rotation, which updates the constant in constraint of topAnchor, but it doesn't change in the view.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - OK... show the code you are using to change the `.constant` property... otherwise there is no way to try to figure out what is not working correctly.

Comment: @DonMag updated the question.

Comment: Are you getting any warning / error messages - such as failed constraints? And... are you saying you check in Debug View Hierarchy in both orientations... each time it shows different *values* but the position is not what the values show? Can you show screen caps of that?

Comment: @DonMag each time they show the value which was set when the view was first shown. I actually just now found a temporary fix by setting isActive to 'false' and back to 'true' in viewWillTransition. (view.top = view.top + 110.4 @ 1100). NO errors.

Comment: hmmm... You should *not* need anything other than setting the `.constant` property. I just did a quick test by changing the constant on a `@IBOutlet` constraint inside `viewWillTransition()`, and, as expected, no problems. It sounds like you have something else going on. I'd suggest you create a new, simple project.. add a view... set the constraints... create an `@IBOutlet` for the top constraint, and change it in `viewWillTransition()`. See that it works... and then figure out what else your code is doing that causes the issue.

Comment: @DonMag I'm really sorry for wasting your time. I solved it. The variable created a new reference (the order of the statements meant that they were separate instances of the constraint and hence did not update in the view). REALLY SORRY. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a variable which created a new reference to the constraint which meant that there were 2 constraints. The order in which the statements were written meant that another instance of the constraint was created thereby causing conflicts. ***My bad***